# How to add function in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How do I add a JavaScript function in React, is this possible? I get 'function is not valid'....

```
//Main component 
function Main () {

const vanilla_JS = function() { console.log('testing')}

 return (
  <main>
   <div>{vanilla_JS}</div>
  </main>

 )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root');
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a javascript function inside a `<div>` ?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443166/4636715

Comment: Why do you need to call functions into JSX and HTML tags? please explain about this use case ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're missing a closing bracket on the `ReactDOM` line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

2) You need to call the function for it to work

```
vanilla_JS()
```

In this working example instead of logging to the console I'm returning a string:

```js
function Main() {

  const vanilla_JS = function() { return 'testing'; }

   return (
    <main>
      <div>{vanilla_JS()}</div>
    </main>
   );

}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```