# Function is not called when state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a function in react showPeople. This is the code:

```
const showPeople = () => {
    const people = workers.map((worker, i) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Worker
                    id={worker.id}
                    index={i}
                    role={worker.role}
                />
            </div>
        )
    })
    return people;
}
```

Later in the component I want to call this function in order to show me some information for the workers. I call it like this:

```
<div>
  {showPeople()}
</div>
```

And this is ok, but it is called only once. When I change the state it's not called. So I have my updates only after I refresh the page. If i remove the parenthesis in the call, I get nothing on my screen. Does anyone knows what's the problem? Sorry if this question is a duplicate, I am not sure I understood any of the previous answers connected tot his topic. Thanks

Comment: please share the entire component, including how you change state

Comment: I think so. I think maybe 'workers' array include keys 'id' and 'role'. But this is my guess only. So share 'workers' array.

Comment: Have you checked with the react-dev-tool or redux-dev-tool to ensure your state is being updated so the component correctly rerenders?

Comment: There is a solution for what I think is the problem with your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443081/how-to-use-function-inside-jsx

Comment: Try this one. <div>{this.showPeople()}</div>

Comment: `<div>{(() => showPeople())()}</div>`

Comment: @k-wasilewski Why are you suggesting to make it more complicated than necessary?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can see the context of the code snippets you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you're probably right, I'm just not used to including functions directly in JSX and know that such code should work

Comment: @k-wasilewski A function call is an expression just like `props.name`. As long as the function returns something JSX can render, then the call is fine. Your example adds extra syntax that ultimately is the same as just calling `showPeople()`.

Comment: Right, now I know that :)

Comment: What is `workers` within `showPeople` function? It isn't defined within function scope.

Comment: `workers`is something i am taking from state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your function to accept workers as parameter:

```
const showPeople = (workers) => {
 const people = workers.map((worker, i) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Worker
                id={worker.id}
                index={i}
                role={worker.role}
            />
        </div>
    )
})
return people;
}
```

And pass workers from state.

```
<div>
 {showPeople(this.state.workers)}
</div>
```

It should re-render whenever your this.state.workers change and it will render with new workers.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is not working. When i debug i can clearly see that the state is updated, and the new value for workers is taken, but it is still not shown in the window. I am taking workers from state like this: `const { workers } = useSelector((state: AppRootState) => state.people); `

Answer (score 0):

As this is written, it should update when ***state*** updates ([see example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-tdd-jsgq2?file=/src/App.js)). Unless you have the array `workers` saved for example like `const {workers} = this.state` or `const [workers, setWorkers] = useState([{'id': '1', role: 'thisRoleNAme'}])` then you may not actually be accessing a piece of state.

Comment: I am accessing the state like this: `const { workers } = useSelector((state: AppRootState) => state.people);`

Comment: is `state.people` an object with a key of workers (for example `{state: {people: {workers: [...], nonWorkers: [...]}}}`)? If not, then `workers` would be undefined and not updated when `state.people` updates. I think at this point there is too much speculation and we would need to see more of your component.